# how to split the data in the unix file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I've a file in Unix (solaris) system with data like below

```
[TYPEA]:/home/typeb/file1.dat
[TYPEB]:/home/typeb/file2.dat
[TYPEB]:/home/typeb/file3.dat
[TYPE_C]:/home/type_d/file4.dat
[TYPE_C]:/home/type_d/file5.dat
[TYPE_C]:/home/type_d/file6.dat
```

I want to separate the headings like below

```
[TYPEA]
/home/typeb/file1.dat
[TYPEB]
/home/typeb/file2.dat
/home/typeb/file3.dat
[TYPE_C]
/home/type_d/file4.dat
/home/type_d/file5.dat
/home/type_d/file6.dat
```

Files with similar type have to come under one type.
Please help me with any logic to achieve this without hardcoding.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input is sorted by type like in your example,

```
awk -F : '$1 != prev { print $1 } { print $2; prev=$1 }' file
```

If there are more than 2 fields you will need to adjust the second clause.

Comment: Not sure off-hand exactly how braindead the default Awk on Solaris is.  You may want to try with `nawk` or `mawk` or look for an XPG Awk if your Solaris Awk out of the box has trouble even with this simple script.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 'H;$ !b
x
s/\(\(\n\)\(\[[^]]\{1,\}]\):\)/\1\2\1/g
:cycle
=;l
s/\(\n\[[^]]\{1,\}]\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/g
t cycle
s/^\n//' YourFile
```

Posix sed version a bit unreadeable due to presence of `[` in pattern
 - allow `:` in label or file/path
 - failed if same label have a line with another label between them (sample seems ordered).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl` you will be able to make use of hashes to create a simple data structure:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %h; 

while(<>){
  chomp;
  my ($key,$value) =  split /:/;
  $h{$key} = [] unless exists $h{$key};
  push ${h{$key}},$value;

}


foreach my  $key (sort keys %h) {
  print "$key"."\n";
  foreach my $value (@{$h{$key}}){
    print "$value"."\n";
  }
}
```

In action:

```
perl script.pl file
[TYPEA]
/home/typeb/file1.dat
[TYPEB]
/home/typeb/file2.dat
/home/typeb/file3.dat
[TYPE_C]
/home/type_d/file4.dat
/home/type_d/file5.dat
/home/type_d/file6.dat
```

If you like it, there is a whole[Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) to solve this simple problem. It's worth reading it.